# winapi - FindWindow vs HCBT_CREATEWND

Tags: winapi

I need to find HWND for the context menu. I create a context menu as in [this](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/163295-microsoft-working-with-menus-part-iii/) tutorial but without submenus.
I can use FindWindow function this way:

```
HWND hWndMenu = FindWindow(TEXT("#32768"), NULL);
```

I can also use the WH_CBT hook. Here is the hook procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        HWND hwnd = (HWND)wParam;
        WCHAR name[1024] = { 0 };
        GetClassName(hwnd, name, sizeof(name));

        if (wcscmp(name, L"#32768"))
        {
            HWND hwndMenu = FindWindow(TEXT("#32768"), NULL);
            std::cout << "HCBT_CREATEWND hwnd: " << hwnd << std::endl;
            std::cout << "FindWindow hwnd: " << hwndMenu << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return code < 0 ? CallNextHookEx(myHook, code, wParam, lParam) : 0;
}
```

When I open context menu I get two different hwnd's. I don't understand why. Could you explain it ?

Comment: Why are you calling `FindWindow` from your CBT procedure? You already have your `HWND` of the expected class type, and then you go looking for it (or another window) all over. Why?

Comment: That's just a simplified example which shows the unexpected result. Shouldn't the values be the same ? What is your understanding ? I would like to use WH_CBT instead of FindWindow because FindWindow doesn't allow to get submenu HWND. Let's assume that I need to send a message MN_SELECITEM to the submenu so I started with a minimal example which tests if sending a message based on WH_CBT works. For the above example sending message to the main menu only works for the HWND returned by FindWindow but because of submenus I would like to use WH_CBT instead of FindWindow and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time the WH_CBT hook is called, the menu window is still in progress of being created but is not yet available to FindWindow(). So, you end up finding another unrelated menu window that exists elsewhere. That is why you are seeing different HWNDs.

Comment: How to find HWND for the submenu ? I have found EnumDesktopWindows function but maybe there is other way ?

Comment: @Irbis well, for starters, you have to wait until after the menu is fully created. I would have the WH_CBT hook PostMessage() a custom message to a private window, then search for the menu when that message is received. Or, at least, do the search in response to HCBT_ACTIVATE instead. Or, look at SetWinEventHook(), instead, which has several events related to menus